# How to add value of dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a row of dataframe to every row of another dataframe.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2],
                 "b": [3,4]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"a":[4], "b":[5]})
```

I want to add df2 value to every row of df1.
I use df1+df2 and get following result

```
    a   b
0   5.0 8.0
1   NaN NaN
```

But I want to get the following result

```
    a   b
0   5   7
1   7   9
```

Any help would be dearly appreciated!

Comment: Try aligning them first: `sum(df1.align(df2, fill_value=0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If really need add values per columns it means number of columns in `df2` is same like number of rows in `df1` use:

```
df = df1.add(df2.loc[0].to_numpy(), axis=0)
print (df)
   a  b
0  5  7
1  7  9
```

---

If need add by rows it means first value of `df1` is add to first column of `df2`, so output is different:

```
df = df1.add(df2.loc[0], axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b
0  5  8
1  6  9
```

Comment: Is it just me or is the second result inaccurate?

Comment: @cs95 - For me more logic here is used secnd answer.

Comment: Result of first output and second output don't match, I mean. Which is correct?

Comment: @cs95 - It is another solution, not matching by original.

Comment: Oh, I get it. For future readers who might have a different use case in mind. Nice foresight!